# How to get Users of a group that are not added in any subgroup In laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$users=Group::find(3)->users;
    $users->whereDoesntHave('subgroups')->get();
```

Its not working as am doing wrong but i don't have any idea how to get result.
Groups and subgroups have many-many relation with users

Comment: show you model relationship

Comment: In user model i added these

` public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }
 public function subgroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SubGroup::class);
    }
`

Comment: $users=Group::find(3)->users;

this line give me all users in group 3 that fine.
Now i want to get only users of group 3 that are not added in any subgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `whereHas` and `has` or `doesntHave` to restrict this query based on the existence of relationships:

```
$groupId = 3;

$users = User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
    $query->where('group_id', $groupId);
})->doesntHave('subgroups')->get();
```

`whereHas` is restricting the Users returned from the query to be only Users who are a part of the Group with 'id' 3. The `doesntHave` is restricting the returned Users to only Users who do not have any relationship to any Subgroup. Combined this query is finding Users who are in Group 3 and do not belong to any Subgroups.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relatinoship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Absense](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)  `doesntHave`

**Update:**

You can restrict the `doesntHave` with conditions by using `whereDoesntHave`:

```
...->whereDoesntHave('subgroups', function ($query) use ($groupId) {
    // depending upon the relationship setup
    $query->where('group_id', $groupId);
})->get();
```

Comment: how to add group_id dynamically??

Comment: you can instruct the closure to use an outside variable ... `use (...)` ... updated the answer to reflect

Comment: that's working really fine dear...
but i have a single problem now i.e.

'->doesntHave('subgroups')->get();'

this clause getting result from all subgroups even that are not part of group_id =3
as i also have relationship between groups and subgroups...

Comment: so Please help it out how it will check only subgroup of group 3

Comment: have you any idea?

Comment: @usama updated, hope that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

With this query you'll get User who has `user_id = 3`  and who Doesn't Have any subgroups

```
$users=  User::whereHas('groups', function($q){
    $q->where('group_id', 3);
})->whereDoesntHave('subgroups')->get()
```